# why some parts of my curve are removed or wiped

Tags: plotting, machine-precision, precision-and-accuracy

When I try to draw the next code I get a curve with missing parts, as shown in the picture. I do not know if it is an precision [image]problem in the Mathematica program or is some data not calculated. Or is it a problem in the way of writing code ?. I'm sure that oriented should be connected.

```
r=2.0;

T=0.05;
β=1/T;
J=1.0;

Clear@UL;UL[B_]:=(


η =Sqrt[J^2+B^2 r^4];

Z=2( Cosh[(2 J β)/r^2]+Cosh[(2 β η)/r^2]);

Subscript[μ, +]=1/(2Z) ( E^(-((2 J β)/r^2))+Cosh[(2 β η)/r^2]-J/η Sinh[(2 β η)/r^2]); 
Subscript[ϵ, -]=1/(2Z) (- E^(-((2 J β)/r^2))+Cosh[(2 β η)/r^2]-J/η Sinh[(2 β η)/r^2]);
Subscript[ϵ, +]=1/(2Z) ( E^((2 J β)/r^2)+Cosh[(2 β η)/r^2]+J/η Sinh[(2 β η)/r^2]);
Subscript[μ, -]=1/(2Z) (-E^(((2 J β)/r^2))+ Cosh[(2 β η)/r^2]+J/ η Sinh[(2 β η)/r^2]);
\[ScriptK]=-((B r^2 Sinh[(2 β η)/r^2])/(2 η Z));

X1=Cosh[(2 J β)/r^2]/Z;
X2=Cosh[(2 J β)/r^2]/Z;
X3=1/Z (Cosh[(2 β η)/r^2]+(B (r^2) )/ η Sinh[(2 β η)/r^2]);
X4=1/Z (Cosh[(2 β η)/r^2]-(B (r^2) )/ η Sinh[(2 β η)/r^2]);
ϖ=Sqrt[(Sinh[(2 J β)/r^2]+J/η Sinh[(2 β η)/r^2])^2+(B^2 r^4 Sinh[(2 β η)/r^2]^2)/ (η^2) ];
Z1=1/4 -ϖ/(2Z);
Z2=1/4 -ϖ/(2Z);
Z3=1/4 +ϖ/(2Z);
Z4=1/4 +ϖ/(2Z);

B1=1/2 (1-4 \[ScriptK]);
B2=1/2 (1+4 \[ScriptK]);

SρσxB=-X1*Log[2,X1]-X2*Log[2,X2]-X3*Log[2,X3]-X4*Log[2,X4];  
SρσzB=-Z1*Log[2,Z1]-Z2*Log[2,Z2]-Z3*Log[2,Z3]-Z4*Log[2,Z4]; 
SρB=-B1*Log[2,B1]-B2*Log[2,B2];

SρσxB+SρσzB-2*SρB)
ULPlot=Plot[UL[B],{B,0.02,10},PlotRange->All]
```

Comment: `UL` evaluates to `Indeterminate` for some values of `B`. Try, for example, `UL /@ {3., 3.1, 3.15, 5.9, 6.}`

Comment: You are right UL evaluates to Indeterminate for some values of B. When I searched why  UL evaluates to Indeterminate I noticed that this was due to the precision of Mathematica  fore examble the values which is Almost equal (\[TildeEqual]) 0.25 the program considers it =0.25 and this leads to ln[.25-0.25] Indeterminate. Do you know how to solve this problem?

Comment: For some values of `B` you have to resolve the limit `Limit[x Log[x],x->0]`. You can manually set it to zero or replace with series.

Comment: Ragab, try (1) rationalize `r`, `T` and `J`, that is define them as `r = 2;T = 5/100;J = 1;` (2)  set precision of `UL` to Infinity, that is, `UL[B_] := SetPrecision[your code, Infinity]` and (3) use a high working precision in `Plot`: e.g., `Plot[UL[B], {B, 0.02, 10}, PlotRange -> All, WorkingPrecision -> 400]`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

(1) Rationalize `r`, `T` and `J`, that is define them as

```
r = 2; T = 5/100; J = 1;
```

(2) Set precision of `UL` to `Infinity`, that is, use

```
 UL[B_] := SetPrecision[your code, Infinity]
```

(3) Use a high working precision in `Plot`: e.g.,

```
 Plot[UL[B], {B, 0.02, 10}, PlotRange -> All, WorkingPrecision -> 400]
```

to get

[image]

**Note:** removed the lines starting with `Subscript[...]=` in `your code` as they are not used anywhere in the rest of your code block.